# Error while trying to build stasm minimal

Tags: c++, image-processing, compiler-errors, g++, stasm

I do not have experience on C++. And I have to use stasm for face detection. I'm traying to build the minimal example. On [page 4 of this tutorial](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.milbo.org%2Fstasm-files%2Fstasm4.pdf) is possible to know what is necessary to make it work. But I'm these two errors:

```
g++ -Wno-deprecated -o teste minimal.cpp `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` -I/home/caaarlos/workspace/StasmDesbravando/stasm 

In file included from minimal.cpp:46:0:
/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/pinstart.cpp: In function ‘void stasm::CopyPoint(stasm::Shape&, const Shape&, int, int)’:
/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/pinstart.cpp:138:13: error: redefinition of ‘void stasm::CopyPoint(stasm::Shape&, const Shape&, int, int)’
static void CopyPoint(     // copy a point from oldshape to shape
         ^
In file included from minimal.cpp:37:0:
/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/convshape.cpp:9:13: error: ‘void stasm::CopyPoint(stasm::Shape&, const Shape&, int, int)’ previously defined here
static void CopyPoint(     // copy a point from oldshape to shape
```

This is my code:

```
// minimal.cpp: Display the landmarks of a face in an image.
//              This demonstrates stasm_search_single.

   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include "opencv/highgui.h"
   #include <opencv/cv.h>

   //#include          "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/stasm_lib.h"
   //#include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/asm.h"
   //#include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/atface.h"
   //#include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/basedesc.h"
   //#include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/classicdesc.h"
   //#include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/convshape.h"
   //#include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/err.h"
   //#include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/eyedet.h"
   //#include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/eyedist.h"
   //#include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/faceroi.h"
   //#include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/hat.h"
   //#include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/hatdesc.h"
   //#include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/landmarks.h"
   //#include        "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/landtab_muct77.h"
   //#include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/misc.h"
   //#include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/pinstart.h"
   //#include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/print.h"
   //#include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/shape17.h"
   //#include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/shapehacks.h"
   //#include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/shapemod.h"
   //#include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/startshape.h"
   //#include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/stasm.h"
   //#include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/stasm_landmarks.h"
   //#include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/stasm_lib.h"
   //#include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/stasm_lib_ext.h"

  #include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/asm.cpp"
  #include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/classicdesc.cpp"
  #include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/convshape.cpp"
  #include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/err.cpp"
  #include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/eyedet.cpp"
  #include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/eyedist.cpp"
  #include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/faceroi.cpp"
  #include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/hat.cpp"
  #include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/hatdesc.cpp"
  #include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/landmarks.cpp"
  #include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/misc.cpp"
  #include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/pinstart.cpp"
  #include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/print.cpp"
  #include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/shape17.cpp"
  #include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/shapehacks.cpp"
  #include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/shapemod.cpp"
  #include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/startshape.cpp"
  #include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/stasm.cpp"
  #include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/stasm_lib.cpp"
  #include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/MOD_1/facedet.h"
  #include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/MOD_1/initasm.h"
  #include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/MOD_1/initasm.cpp"
  #include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/MOD_1/facedet.cpp"

  using namespace cv;
  using namespace std;

  int main()
  {
    static const char* const path = "../data/testface.jpg";

cv::Mat_<unsigned char> img(cv::imread(path, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE));

if (!img.data)
{
    printf("Cannot load %s\n", path);
    exit(1);
}


int foundface;
float landmarks[2 * stasm_NLANDMARKS]; // x,y coords (note the 2)

if (!stasm_search_single(&foundface, landmarks,
                         (const char*)img.data, img.cols, img.rows, path, "../data"))
{
    printf("Error in stasm_search_single: %s\n", stasm_lasterr());
    exit(1);
}

if (!foundface)
     printf("No face found in %s\n", path);
else
{
    // draw the landmarks on the image as white dots (image is monochrome)
    stasm_force_points_into_image(landmarks, img.cols, img.rows);
    for (int i = 0; i < stasm_NLANDMARKS; i++)
        img(cvRound(landmarks[i*2+1]), cvRound(landmarks[i*2])) = 255;
}

cv::imwrite("minimal.bmp", img);
cv::imshow("stasm minimal", img);
cv::waitKey();
return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling my code in thi way:

```
g++ -Wno-deprecated -o teste minimal.cpp `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` -I/home/caaarlos/workspace/StasmDesbravando/stasm
```

What am I doing wrong? Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: `#include "/home/caaarlos/Documentos/TCC/stasm4.1.0/stasm/asm.cpp"` What? You need to learn how to use a build system like CMake, this is terrible! (No offense, but this is really unusable on any system but yours.)

Comment: Can you show me a way to learn it? Thanks for your reply... Like I said, I did not know c++, but I have to use stasm.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad for your help!!

Comment: There are many build systems out there, and many good tutorials for each of them. <opinion> CMake is probably the most popular right now </opinion>, so go and use your favorite search engine to find a good tutorial and follow it. Don't worry, this is not hard.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it. But, if I use CMake my compilation will work? Or the CMake use is just to make my code reusable?

Comment: No, the CMake-advice was not supposed to answer your question, but only to help you write better code. That's why I posted it as a comment and not as an answer. :) I do not know stasm and I do not know what you did wrong, but providing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would certainly help the folks here to provide you a nice and clear answer.

Comment: Ok, I'll change my question and study CMake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for this problem. If somebody has a problem like mine, you should enter on [this site](https://github.com/juan-cardelino/stasm) and use the CMakeList.txt and CMake to build Stasm. If you get any error you can try the intructions provides o the readme.